# footer automatically take height according to screen

Tags: html, css, footer

I am creating a webpage.I want my footer automatically increase height from his starting to the end of the screen if i decrease the content of middle div.Before that people ask about stucking the div to the bottom but i want to increase automatic height.

[image]

In this upper image the footer goes up and empty space produced which is not good.Now i dont want it stucks to bottom i want its height increased automatically from its starting to the end of doc.

My code for footer div is

```
#Footer {
background-color: #933;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: #000;
```

}

Comment: Didn;t get you can you make it clear.

Comment: @VIVEkUI in the upper pic the footer goes up,after end of footer there is lot of empty space which don not looks good. I want that footers height automatically increased to the end point of the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kq5Q/4/)**

**JS**

```
function autoResizeDiv()
        {
            document.getElementById('Footer').style.height = window.innerHeight +'px';
        }
        window.onresize = autoResizeDiv;
        autoResizeDiv();
```